# Export contributions - missing Field Mapping dropdown

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, field-mapping

I was able to reproduce on CIVICRM DEMO site: https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk
Steps to reproduce:

1. Find contributions
2. Select contributions
3. Select action 'Export contributions'
4. Select option 'Select fields for export'

A dropdown should display to let use select fields for mapping but in civicrm version 5 that div id '#map' do not have any content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work. If you don't have mapping saved then it won't display the list. I tested on https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/ after saving the mapping. Second time i visited the page i could see mapping field. Make sure you have mappings saved for contribution export.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, it worked on demo site. But on our site we have many mappings saved already. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/kj1qbx

Site was recently upgraded from 4.6.38 to 5.4.0 and there are no custom php or template files. Also i created a new mapping just now, it got saved but then again if i try to export that new or any other mapping do not shows

Comment: sorry, there was a custom file that was causing the problem. Thank you!

Comment: So can we mark this as answered?